Use of SAS Token appended to the URLs to all resources in Azure Storage Container
I have a static web site including a HTML page, a few style and script files and images. They are stored in an Azure Storage Container. There is a Shared Access Signature (SAS) set up on the entire Container.
BLOB_TOKEN = '?sp=rl&st=2024-12-05T13:00:00Z&se=2025-12-06T13:00:00Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=SOME_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS'

In the HTML page, I had to explicitly appended the BLOB_TOKEN to every single URL for individual script, style files, images and all the other links (a href) to be able to properly load the resources.
For example,
<script>
    const TK = '?sp=rl&st=2024-12-05T13:00:00Z&se=2025-12-06T13:00:00Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=SOME_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS'

    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/my_style_1.css"+ TK + "' \/>");
    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/my_script_1.js"+ TK + "'><\/script>");
</script>

<img src="img/UserUploadedImages/logo.png?sp=rl&st=2024-12-05T13:00:00Z&se=2025-12-06T13:00:00Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=SOME_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS" width="60px" height="60px"/>

I would like to know if there is a better way to use SAS for all resources. Is it possible to configure the Azure Container to allow the html page to use any other resources in the same Container without having to attaching the SAS string to the URL of the resource?

You can create the SAS token at container level, but you will still need to include it in the URL to request specific resourced within that container. That being said, if you're using the container to serve public HTML/CSS etc, why not set the container to allow public access to blobs without enumeration of all files?

You can make use of static website hosting feature of Azure Storage. Then you would not even need this SAS token at all.

I agree with @Gaurav Mantri that you can use Azure storage static website here to achieve your requirement.
Firstly, you need to enable static website in Azure Blob storage. Go to Data management -> Static website -> Enable.
Here, give the default index page name and error page name as shown below.

Now, a new container named $web will be created in the storage account. You can upload all of your images, scripts, html files to this container.
You can use the below URL to test your index.html file.

You need to specify the file path as per folder structure that you have given while uploading. Here, for sample, I have used below code to test the index.html page.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>This is the index page</h1>
        <img src="/sub1/Luffy and shanks.jpg" width="60px" height="60px"/>
  </body>
</html>


Result:

You can do the same from your local visual studio code as well. You can go through this documentation to know more about it.

@Alextc: Good to accept the solution if it has helped. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO link
